# how to use logger to write info to log

Tags: logs, bsd, logger

I want to use the logger command in order to write logs to /var/log/server.log

NOTE: These examples use the FreeBSD version of logger. Your system may have different options, so read your local documentation!

```
logger -p INFO -f /var/log/server.log -t MY_LOG_TAG "server is up"
```

*This suppose to send the message to be logged in /var/log/server.log with the info, It includes a tag (-t MY_LOG_TAG), which is included in each line.*

but the syntax with the logger not append the log to /var/log/server.log

please advice what is wring with the logger syntax ?

**second is it possible to add the date in the log line ?**

**expected output**

```
Wed Mar 6 18:16:54 UTC 2019 INFO server is up
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood the `-f` option.

From [the FreeBSD `logger(1)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=logger&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html):

> `-f file`
>
> Read the contents of the specified file into syslog.  This option
>            is ignored when a message is also specified.

The `logger` utility will send the message to the syslog service (by default on the local machine) and depending on its configuration and the priority/tag of the message, it will be appended to one or several log files.  You can't log to a *specific* log file without [configuring syslog](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syslog.conf&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) to treat your log messages specially.